# One scaler for all features or one scaler per feature?

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, data-cleaning

I have a time series with more than 30 features. For preprocessing with scikit learn do you usually use one scaler per feature or one scaler for all features that should be standardized/normalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use one scaler per feature. This will make sure that the values are preserved and just scaled.

**Example**

```py
# Data
feature_1 feature 2
 1         1
 2         2
 5         3
10         5
```

Using one scaler for all features will scale the data based on the minimum and maximum values for all data points. This will results in the following.

```py
# One scaler for all features
 feature_1 feature 2
 .1         .1
 .0         .0
 .5         .3
1.0         .5
```

Using a different scaler for each feature will make sure that each individual feature is scaled, maintaining the data.

```py
# One scaler per feature
 feature_1 feature 2
 .1         .2
 .0         .0
 .5         .6
1.0        1.0
```